# My form is not sending data to the mySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

I have been working on this website/database for days, and it will not send input data from forms to the actual mySQL database. This is the PHP and code for the file that I am working in:

```
$host = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "database";

        try {
            $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $sql = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO beginv (barID, barName, manName, dateUploaded) VALUES (:barid, :barname, :manname, :dateUp");
            $sql->bindParam(':barid', $_POST["barid"]);
            $sql->bindParam(':barname', $_POST["barname"]);
            $sql->bindParam(':manname', $_POST["man_name"]);
            $sql->bindParam(':dateUp', $_POST["txt_date"]);

            if($con->exec($sql)) {
                echo "Request sent successfully";
            }

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        ?>
```

and this is the HTML for the input form:

```
<form method="post" action=""><br>
                <center><h1>BEGINNING INVENTORY</h1></center>
                <br>
                <form>
                    <div class="div4">
                        <label for="barid">Bar ID: </label><br>
                        <input type="number" class="textbox" id="barid" name="barid" style="width: 690px" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="div2">
                        <label for="barname">Bar Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="textbox" id="barname" name="barname" style="width: 690px" />
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div4">
                        <label for="man_name">Manager: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="textbox" id="man_name" name="man_name" style="width: 690px" />
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div2">
                        <label for="txt_date">Date (yyyy-mm-dd): </label>
                        <input type="text" class="textbox" id="txt_date" name="txt_date" style="width: 690px" />
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I have hardcoded an SQL statement into this, and it did go through to the database. This goes to show that the connection to the database is working, but the input data is not going through.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php should be used not `exec()`.

Comment: Is that PHP code in the same file as the form? It should be. Have you tried something like: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {var_dump($_POST)}` to check the form data is getting to the script?

Comment: The answer is right to point out that you should not have two form elements in there. Get rid of the first one but put the two attributes in it into the second form element.

Answer (score 0):

Hello in your code you are writing two form remove the second one and add action file path in you are sending data to same file in modify action to

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
```

Comment: `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>` is open to XSS injections.